# how can we retrieve two variables in one line if else

Tags: ruby

```
("string" != "string") ? (article = '-' , contact_info = '-') : (article = '' , contact_info = '')
```

How can I update this condition then it will return two variables now its output is an array like ["-" , "-"]

Comment: `"string" != "string"` doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: just a condition for understanding issue is I want to get to two variables in return

Answer (score 3):

I believe this should work:

`article, contact_info = ("string" != "string") ? ['-', '-'] : ['' , '']`

In ruby you can assign multiple variables from an array using:

[Multiple Assignement](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Just return arrays?

```
("string" != "string") ? ['-', '-'] : ['' , '']
```